# Registro de logs de Errores en Asp.net 1.1

Tags: asp.net

alguien sabe como puedo registrar logs de errores no controlados en asp.net (vs2003 .net 1.1). Actualmente tengo esto en el web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="paginaDeError.htm"/>
```

Pero esa pagina de error muestra un mensaje genérico, aparte de mostrar ese mensaje necesito que en algún lado me registre la excepción completa con el mensaje pila etc, alguien me puede colaborar en lograr aquello.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias ver si puedes habilitar `ELMAH`

[elmah site](https://elmah.github.io/)

[ELMAH nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah/)

este permite llevar un log detallado que podrias analizar.

Sino otra alternativa podrias ser quitar el `<customErrors` y definir alguna otra forma de redireccionar despues de loguear el problema

[ASP.NET Error Handling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling)

podrias definir el evento `Application_Error`

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

    //aqui registras el error en algun log

    if (exc is HttpUnhandledException)
    {
        // Pass the error on to the error page.
        Server.Transfer("ErrorPage.aspx", true);
    }
}
```

entonces en este puedes tomar el exception, registrarlo y luego redireccionar a la pagina que muestra el mensaje generico